# Consuming json values from a kafka topic and writing them and formatting them in a csv file using JQ

Tags: json, csv, kafka-consumer-api, jq

I am trying to write into a csv file keys and values that are in a kafka topic. I have been able to select the keys and values that I want, but I am not able to get them separated by rows (three values per row values in rows separated by commas).

This is an example of two json records that I consumed from my kafka topic without doing any filtering. The command that I used is:

`./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer --bootstrap-server kafka1.example.net:9092 --topic prod.example.v1 --max-messages 2 | jq -r '. '`

`{
  "count": "0",
  "source": 3,
  "lastModified": "2018-03-09T21:03:54.039Z",
  "isBusiness": false,
  "countryCode": " MX",
  "phone": "52/4446789864"
}
{
  "count": "0",
  "source": 3,
  "lastModified": "2018-03-09T21:03:54.039Z",
  "isBusiness": false,
  "countryCode": " GB",
  "phone": "44/0187567846"
}`

I tried using this command, but each value is being put into its own row:

`./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer --bootstrap-server kafka1.example.net:9092 --topic prod.example.v1 --max-messages 3 | jq -r ' .isBusiness, .countryCode, .phone ' > file.csv`

Ideal output would be:

```
false, MX, 52/4446789864
false, GB, 44/0187567846
true, BE, 32/8745687645
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jq -r '[.isBusiness, .countryCode, .phone] | @csv'
```

produces CSV:

```
false," MX","52/4446789864"
false," GB","44/0187567846"
```

The filter:

```
"\(.isBusiness), \(.countryCode), \(.phone)"
```

produces

```
false,  MX, 52/4446789864
false,  GB, 44/0187567846
```

You might want to "trim" the string values, e.g. using:

```
def trim: sub("^ +";"") | sub(" +$";"");
```